# is there a way to know if any commits done in current session of sqlite database

Tags: sqlite

I need to create SQLite database backup but I need to do it when any new transaction has been committed. I do not want to create a backup if nothing has been changed. is there a way to know if any commits done in the current session of the SQLite database?

I am already keeping a bool variable (in sqlite c++ wrapper class) to store db change information but it will only work for 'main' database file, i am attaching several other databases to 'main' database so i need to know changed status of attached db as well for backup purpose.

Comment: For other connections changing a database, there's [PRAGMA data_version](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_data_version). For in the same connection... Yeah, just set a flag whenever you `COMMIT` or run an `INSERT` or `UPDATE` outside of a bigger transaction.

Comment: @Shawn sqlite3_total_changes tells that if there was any modification or not, but not sure how to get this info for attached database.

Comment: Different counters for different databases.